# @GeneratedValue not having the @Id usage while updating from persistence object

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an entity which have the composite primary keys but none have the `@GeneratedValue` and another column which has the `@GeneratedValue` but not a primary key.

And now i am calling the setter method of the persistence object and the error i am getting is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot update identity column '<column name of the @GeneratedValue but not a primary key>'.`

Is there any way that i can avoid this error and still use the setter methods to update?

Comment: As per the JPA spec, `@GeneratedValue` is only supported on `@Id` fields. I know that DataNucleus JPA supports it on any field, but others (most?) don't.